# How do I order my SQL Server database from SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, database, sorting

Before I get adding way to much data into this database I wanted to ask this question, how can I sort this table like in Excel to display by alphabetical order permanently? Or do I have to input it manually the first time?

[image: Database]

Comment: Sounds like you want a [clustered index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/clustered-and-nonclustered-indexes-described?view=sql-server-2017).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misunderstanding a fundamental concept about SQL:  tables represent *unordered* sets.  They have no ordering.  So, there is simply no such thing as an "ordered table".

If you want the results in a particular order, you need to use an `ORDER BY` clause on the query.  Period.  That is how SQL works.

There is one capability in SQL Server that is suspiciously close to an ordered table -- clustered indexes.  When a table has a clustered index, the data is sorted on the data pages by the index keys.  However, this does not guarantee that a `SELECT` will actually return the rows in that order.

Answer (score 0):

To keep it simple, add an order by clause.

```
SELECT <columns>
FROM <table>
ORDER BY <COLUMN> ASC OR DESC
```

Comment: That Simply Returns A Result, it's only temporary until I close the results, I want to know how I sort the table permanently so that every time the server is loaded it's already sorted